# Fetch data from database using ajax in jsp and spring

Tags: spring

```
      i have dropdown a label in that already values are  coming from database using spring jsp & mysql , now i need to apply ajax search in my dropdown or text box .How can i apply in my jsp spring forms ??
```

example: 
controller@
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBank1")
    public ModelAndView addBank(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String entityType) {

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allbankAccounts = accService
            .getAllbankAccounts(entityType);
    model.addAttribute("allbankAccounts", allbankAccounts);
```

}

Jsp@

```
                       <p class="text-muted font-13">
            <strong>Bank name </strong>                               
            <span class="m-l-15">
            <form:select class="form-
              control" path="empQufnId" title="Select" id="report">
          <form:option value="" label="Select 
          bank name" />
          <c:forEach items="${allbankAccounts}" 
          var="sal" varStatus="status"
            <form:option path="empQufnId" 
           value="${sal.bankId}" >${sal.bankName}</form:option>     
                        </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
```